Отсутствие ускорения работы с бд в оперативной памяти sqlite3 python
Столкнулся с полным непониманием того, почему при работе с БД не на жёстком диске, а в оперативной памяти, абсолютно не чувствуется ускорения. Вроде, делаю всё как в интернет туториалах, где пишут об ускорении в 3-4 раза, а эффект на уровне погрешности.
import sqlite3
import random
import datetime

def addPeople(num_of_people, cursor, connection):
    for i in range(num_of_people):
        id = i
        name = "name{0}".format(id)
        age = random.randint(0, 100)
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO People (id, name, age) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (id, name, age))

    connection.commit()

def showData(cursor):
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM People')
    People = cursor.fetchall()
    print(len(People))

def common():
    connection = sqlite3.connect('my_database.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS People (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    age INTEGER
    )
    ''')

    addPeople(10000000, cursor, connection)

    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    showData(cursor)
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(end - start, end="\n\n")

    connection.close()

def in_memory_compute():
    connection = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS People (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        name TEXT NOT NULL,
        age INTEGER
        )
        ''')

    addPeople(10000000, cursor, connection)

    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    showData(cursor)
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(end - start, end="\n\n")

    connection.close()


def main():

    common()

    in_memory_compute()

main()

Результат выполнения прилагается:
enter image description here
Я попробовал несколько способов открывания бд в оперативной памяти, с других ответов на stackoverflow, но ничего путного так и не вышло. Помогите пожалуйста :)

Потому что расположение базы абсолютно никак не повлияет на лютую тормознутость этого кода

В общем оказалось, что я как всегда заблуждался в своих предположениях. Код, как упоминалось выше, очень плох. Сейчас разобрался с своей проблемой, спасибо :)
